# Lumen Route redirect to 404 in Nginx

Tags: php, .htaccess, nginx, lumen

I am doing one project in lumen, and I have installed this in my LAMP server. I have use a htaccess file to strip index.php from url.
here is my htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Here everything is working fine.
Now I am moving my files to newly created instance with LEMP stack server (nginx). This is lumen file, so I have installed composer in my project directory.
when I am putting a test route in url (browser), (eg: website.com/getUser) it is showing 404 page error.

SO I have modified the nginx default file in /etc/nginx/sites-available/default

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    server_name _;
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
        #try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        #       fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }  
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

and then I have created a separate server block file for my website by copying the **default** file and making some changes. that file is below.

```
server {
    listen 80 ;
    listen [::]:80 ;
    root /var/www/html/my.website.com;
    server_name my.website.com;
    location / {
        rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 redirect;
        if (!-e $request_filename){
            rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php break;
        }
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Now, when I typing my url (website.com/getUser), then it is downloading something. after opening in sublime, I get to know that this file is actually index.php which is in root directory of my project (website.com/index.php)

I am not getting, why it is happening. Why I am not be able to access my route. Where is the problem, can you guys help me in this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your config:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
```